# What happen if I kill living stock (sheep, chicken, cow)?

Tags: kingdom-come-deliverance

I would like to know what happen if I kill living stock (sheep, cow, chicken).

In two scenario:

- Someone see me kill their chicken (I shot arrow in the chicken in front of them)
- Nobody see me killing thing (I kill sheep, cow when they are on the grassland and nobody nearby)

Answer (score 3):

If someone sees you harming cattle, they will run/call for a guard, and you'll be fined/sent to jail. It's a very good way to lose during the prologue in Skalitz...

If noone sees you, you've just found living punching bags to improve you strength ! :-)

NB :
I'm pretty sure that punching chickens does not trigger a guard call. But using a weapon to do so might though.

Comment: I did not just punch, I kill (shot with arrow, sword... ). Does people noted it when they find their sheeps dead ?

Comment: I think NPCs react to dead people only, not dead animals, but hey do react to both people and animals being hit/shot (except maybe the aforementionned chickens).